# html drill down drop down selected value does not inserted in MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

i have two drop downs. first drop down populate from database. second drop down populated from database based on selected value of first drop down.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#c").change(function() {
    var c1 = $('#c :selected').text();
    if(c1 != "") {
      $.ajax({
        url:'getstatw.php',
        data:{c:c1},
        type:'POST',
        success:function(response) {
          var resp = $.trim(response);
          $("#c").html(resp);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#c").html("<option value=''>Select state</option>");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
 <form id = "world" method="post" action="insert.php">
<select name="country" id="c" style = "width:200px" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" ;>
      <option>country</option>
  
      <?php
          
      $sql = "select DISTINCT country from table1";
      $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) {
          echo "<option value='".$row->id."'>".$row->c."</option>";
    
        }
      }
      ?>
    </select>
<br><br>
  <label for="s" >State</label>

<select name="State" id="s" style = "width:200px  " ; class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle";><option>Select state</option></select><br><br>
<button id = "sub" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```

insert.php

```js
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","world");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
//home tab
$c = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['country']);
$s = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['state']);


//query for table_mainast
$sql1="INSERT INTO table1 (Country, State)
VALUES ('$c', '$s',)";
//query for table_dataast


if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
```

getstate.php

```js
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['c'])) {
  $sql = "select DISTINCT `State` from `table2` where `Country`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['c'])."'";
  $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
     echo "<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) {
      echo "<option value='".$row->id."'>".$row->c."</option>";
    }
  }
} else {
  header('location: ./');
}


?>
```

i have tried almost all solution given on net. but do not understand my data is not inserted into mysql database. 
[How to insert HTML select value as text in MySQL via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121363/how-to-insert-html-select-value-as-text-in-mysql-via-php)
[PHP Drop down list selected value not inserted in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666685/php-drop-down-list-selected-value-not-inserted-in-the-database)

Answer (score 0):

You need to concantenate them properly and also you don't you put `,` after last column in the query

Change following

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO table1 (Country, State)
VALUES ('$c', '$s',)";
```

to

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO table1 (country, state)
VALUES ('".$c."', '".$s."')";
```

Comment: i have also tried this but this data is not insertes

Comment: @Sarah_Salar Can you please let me know if any error showing ?

Comment: dose not give error . just do not insert values into table. after submitting table is blank. no record inserted

Comment: WHY NOBODY HELP ON THIS FORUM

Comment: @Sarah_Salar Already did answer, can you kindly check you table columns

Comment: if this solution helps me it would not post here. i checked it

Comment: the problem is with dropdown. when i send indivdual values to datasebase using code c = $('#Country :selected').text(); it store into database @Mr.Developer

Answer (score 0):

if want to add options to the second drop down you need to use `append` not `html` and your using same ID i.e. `#c` to write the response in ajax success, change it to second drop down ID i.e. `#s`

you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#c").change(function() {
    var c1 = $('#c :selected').text();
    if(c1 != "") {
      $.ajax({
        url:'getstatw.php',
        data:{c:c1},
        type:'POST',
        success:function(response) {
          var resp = $.trim(response);
          $("#s").append(resp);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#c").append("<option selected value=''>Select state</option>");
    }
  });
});
```

then remove  `,` in insert query.

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO table1 (Country, State)
VALUES ('$c', '$s')";
```

Comment: kindly look at this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49043561/insert-two-array-and-variable-value-into-mysql-table-with-single-query